# How light strike works?

Tags: sensor, light, laser

I am new here and I don't know if I have chosen right stackexchange but anyway.

I am making a little toy, just for educational purpose. I would like to understand how light strike works. It is a gun which lights some light, sensor somehow detects it and count the points.

I am wondering because it works even in day light.

It is similar to Laser Tag, which I understand, because you must be in dark place and you "shoot" laser beams. But how come that Light Strike doesn't shoot direct light. Is it some radio wave?

Even if you can't answer the question, don't you have any advice how to shoot something what can be received by some sensor?

Comment: Probably infra-red - just like a TV remote control.

Comment: Very great, I totally forgot about remote control. And dont you know if there is any possibility of providing different signals? Omg yes of course it is... if you press #1 sensor on the TV gets #1. That is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is similar to Laser Tag, which I understand, because you must be in
>   dark place and you "shoot" laser beams. But how come that Light Strike
>   doesn't shoot direct light. Is it some radio wave?

James Clerk Maxwell in the 1800s basically proved that light and radio waves are exactly the same thing. Just thought I'd get that out of the way first.

More than likely it uses a low power infra red (invisible) laser and the laser will be modulated with a signal that makes it instantly recognizable from changes in ambient lighting conditions.

Using a laser ensures a tight beam is "fired" at the target.

The sensor(s) will be an IR detector (likely) with an amplifier and decoder (for the modulation) and upon decoding the signal it will advance points on some scoreboard or other.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask you also if it is possible to limit the IR so it works only if you aim somewhere around the sensor? Btw check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEGmzJuH3Ew#t=12 I found out that it is just normal light probably. Anyway very thanks for the IR idea.

Comment: I repair BattleSports guns, which use IR. They just use a normal IR LED, but it's focussed with a lens.

Comment: @OndrejTokar you can focus or defocus the beam or use multiple sensors to do what you want.